# How to make a HTML table <TD> invisible

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a Grid View and I am checking some permission on the Grid View

If the user don't have permission. I am making the column invisible.

```
    Grid View.Column[9].visible = false; //Zero based index so column 10 will be invisible.
```

The GridView doesn't use GridView's header (because of a specific
styling issue) but a separate html table.

the header is defined as follows

```
<tr>
            <td width="5%" class="hier-header">Column 1</td>
            <td width="10%"  class="hier-header"> Column 2 </td>
            <td width="10%"  class="hier-header"> Column 3</td>
            <td width="10%"  class="hier-header"> Column 4</td>
            <td width="5%"   class="hier-header"> Column 5</td>
            <td width="5%"   class="hier-header"> Column 6</td>
            <td width="10%"  class="hier-header"> Column 7 </td>
            <td width="15%"  class="hier-header"> Column 8 </td>
            <td width="5%"   class="hier-header"> Column 9 </td>
            <td width="5%"   class="hier-header"> Column 10 </td>
            <td width="5%"   class="hier-header"> Column 11</td>
            <td width="5%"   class="hier-header">Column 12</td>
            <td width="5%"   class="hier-header">Column 13</td>
    </tr>
```

In the above code I should make Column 10 not to show up. Is this doable?

Comment: You could try to set a certain CSS class with `display: none;` and/or `visibility: hidden;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a `runat="server"` attribute to the `<td>` for Column 10 and give it an ID (like `id="column10Header"`). Then you can set its `Visible` property to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add id to the column you want to be hidden then in backend set id.visible=false;

Comment: Don't forget the `runat="server"` as @michael pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Give the td you want a new class. So that would be `class="hier-header invisible"`. Then make everything with `.invisible` invisible using the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things, hide column10 with css class (eg. Mr Lister answer) but then markup will be rendered and user can look in the source and see this data, so if you have some sensitive information in column10 you better set runat="server" and set visible to false, and column 10 will not be rendered in response html at all.